# Defining JSONP callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a bit new to JS and I'm having some problems with my code.

I have Ajax request to the server, from which I get the response. Since it's cross-domain request, I'm using JSONP.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "***",
    contentType: 'application/javascript',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "parseResponse"
  })
    .done(function (response) {
        doSomething();
    })
    .fail(function (error)) {
        console.log(error);
  }
```

Response that I get:

```
parseResponse({...})
```

My problem is with understanding how parseResponse callback works. With this code I SOMETIMES get

> *"Uncaught ReferenceError: parseResponse is not defined"*.

But part of responses get through OK (in *.done* function I filter response and from there, I fill a table).

How should be parseResponse defined correctly?

EDIT:
"parseResponse" is default callback set by Geoserver service.

Example of response:

```
parseResponse({"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":"unknown","features":[],"crs":null})
```

Typically features property array would be filled with some data.

Comment: "Since it's cross-domain request, I'm using JSONP."  Use CORS instead.  JSON-P hasn't been necessary in years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `jsonpCallback: "parseResponse"` from your [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call. That lets jQuery handle all the work for you. (It creates a unique function name, creates the function, passes the name to the endpoint, and cleans up the function when done.)

Also remove the `contentType: "application/javascript"`. You're not *sending* JavaScript code to the server.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "***", // <== Make sure this DOESN'T have ?callback= on it
    dataType: "jsonp"
})
.done(function(response) {
    doSomething();
})
.fail(function(error)) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

---

According to your comments, the target service (Geoserver) requires a ridiculous option for specifying the JSONP callback: `format_options=callback:name`. That doesn't play nicely with `ajax` at all (and I've never seen such obtuse support for JSONP before).

To handle it while not using a hardcoded name (because hardcoded names are a bad idea, you can't overlap calls), we have to play silly games like this:

```
var callbackName = "myJSONPCallback" + Date.now() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
$.ajax({
    url: "//the-url?format_options=callback:" + callbackName,
    // Include ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // in the URL
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: callbackName
})
.done(function(response) {
    doSomething();
})
.fail(function(error)) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

See `ajax` documentation (linked above) for details of the `jsonp` and `jsonpCallback` options.

Comment: "parseResponse" is default callback set by service (I'm dealing with Geoserver). With jsonpCallback set in my code I get some responses through, without it I get only "Uncaught ReferenceError: parseResponse is not defined".

Comment: @pc9529: Presumably Geoserver supports the standard JSONP callback parameter on the query string. Remember "default" is just that: A *default*. It doesn't mean you have to use the default. If they require that particular function name, that's fairly pathetic of them. :-) Look in the documentation.

Comment: As I understand, name of the callback needs to be set manually to one, or the default one is used (parseResponse). So there's not much choice, since it will always return parseResponse({...}) (or defined name)

Comment: @pc9529: Normally, with JSONP, you specify the name of the callback in the query string (via `?callback=theNameGoesHere`) and the server respects that. When using `ajax`, you don't put that in the URL yourself because `ajax` will add it for you (with the generated name). It's possible, but **unlikely**, that Geoserver requires a specific name.

Comment: Geoserver, uses default parseReponse callback, unless specified differently in query string under `format_options=callback:name`.

Comment: @pc9529: That would be really poor support for JSONP. Where is the documentation you're looking at?

Comment: @pc9529: `ajax` can (just) handle that though; I've updated to show how.

Comment: Thank you so much :) It works now. Is there any particular way in which callback function needs to be executed? Code executes, table gets filled, but  `.fail` function still executes with code 200 and readyState 4 (done). it's supposed to be error with content, but it looks fine to me.

Comment: @pc9529: The JSONP response is what calls the function. Can you post an example of what the response is (from the Network tab) to the question?

Comment: I've added an example of response, i go through features array and get data from there.

Comment: @pc9529: That example is valid, other than that it **still** uses `parseResponse`. If you're using the code above, it shouldn't be. So it's using the wrong function name despite our sending the correct option (presumably you've done that correctly). I'm afraid I have no idea what the problem is. I've used the exact ajax call above to double-check syntax and such and it was just fine (but of course, I'm not querying Geoservice).

Comment: My bad, response is using right function name in my case. Responses are all valid (I've validated them manually). Thanks for your help, much appreaciated